# String to Color Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, colors, xamarin.forms

How to convert string to color in xamarin.from , there isn't Color.fromName method ?

```
string colorStr = "Blue";
BoxView objBoxView = new BoxView
{
    HeightRequest = double.Parse(HeightRequest),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
    BackgroundColor = colorStr
};
```

Comment: `BackgroundColor = Color.Blue` will do it

Comment: Maaan I know that , I need string to convert in Color because "blue"come from the json file but I simple wrote "blue" !!

Comment: ColorTypeConverter -> You should take a look at this class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some examples using ColorTypeConverter with string values from the test TestColorTypeConverter in ColorUnitTests.cs in the [Xamarin.Forms github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/):

```
var input = new[]
{
    "blue", "Blue", "Color.Blue",     // by name
    "#0000ff", "#00f",                // by hex code
    "#a00f",                          // by hex code with alpha
    "rgb(0,0, 255)", "rgb(0,0, 300)", // by RGB
    "rgba(0%,0%, 100%, .8)",          // by RGB percent with alpha
    "hsl(240,100%, 50%)",             // by HSL
    "hsla(240,100%, 50%, .8)",        // by HSL with alpha
    "Accent",                         // by Accent color
    "Default", "#12345"               // not a valid color
};

ColorTypeConverter converter = new ColorTypeConverter();

foreach (var str in input)
{
    Color color = (Color)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(str));
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} is {1} Color", str, color.IsDefault ?  "not a" : "a");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah, unfortunately there isn't, but you may use the following:

```
var strColor = "Blue";    
var color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(strColor);
boxColor.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [`Color.FromHex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.color.fromhex?view=xamarin-forms) will parse a color name into a `Color` value for you, e.g.

```
Color background = Color.FromHex("blue"); // #0000FF
```

This at least works as of Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.  I don't see this explicitly promised in the referenced documentation, so who knows - they may modify this in the future.  Might be good to see how this fares against XF 5.

Answer (score -1):

Added this converter into our [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AscendantWare.Xamarin.Essentials/).

```
using AscendantWare.Xamarin.Essentials.Tools;

String MyColor = "Red";
Color cRed = MyColor.ToColor();
```

More Informations [here](https://ascendantware.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/articles/AWXE-A-9/).